# I have a field in database which I do not want to map in my spring java model while making a get call

Tags: spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I have a database table in which there is a field which I do not want to map to my model class while making a  get call. Is there any annotation to handle this use case?

Comment: Just don't include it in your entity class.

Answer (score 1):

When persisting Java objects into database records using an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) framework, we can ignore fields by adding the `@Transient` annotation to those fields.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
 
    private String email;
 
    private String password;
 
    @Transient
    private Date loginTime;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```